# Getting HighStock javascript chart to show the latest tooltip on load

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using the javascript chart from highcharts.com called HighStock for one of my online solutions and the client asked me if there is any way of getting it to show the tooltip for the latest data-point when the graph has been loaded.

I have searched high and low on google, here on stackoverflow and also created a topic about this on their support forum a week ago (no replies yet, though), but I can't really find anything about it. Of course, I have tried to find a solution for this myself, but without any luck.

So, if there anyone out there, that knows how to achieve this? If it is possible at all? :-)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Now with fiddler link: http://jsfiddle.net/L2TFd/ This is basically just one of the examples from highsoft themselves since I can't access my webservices from other domains :-)

This is the tooltip of the last point I want to show when graph is done loading:

[image]

Comment: Hi Hardik, yes sure - give me a second and I'll post the link here :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate "show the tooltip for the latest data-point". I am not exactly getting what you are trying to get

Comment: Sure, Hardik :-) When the graph is done loading all the data (all the points), my client wants to show the tooltip for the very last point in the graph. Don't know if that describes the problem better? If not, please let me know :-) Thanks again!

Comment: By "showing the tooltip" he means when you hover one of the points, the tooltip with the data shows - that's what he wants to show when the data has been loaded.